# EXC BAD ACCESS on property with overriden object

Tags: ios, swift

This is my simple test:

```
func testInitWithResponseAsDictionaryAndStatusFalse() {

    let operation = WLMockRequestOperation()
    operation.responseObject = "asdsa" //here is an error
}
```

The error is:

> Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x0)

And this is my `WLMockRequestOperation` class:

```
class WLMockRequestOperation: AFHTTPRequestOperation {

    var myOverridenResponseObject: AnyObject?

    override var responseObject: AnyObject? {

        get {
            return myOverridenResponseObject
        }

        set {
            myOverridenResponseObject = newValue
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Try "clean" your project. It helps sometimes.

Comment: Tried some times. It didn't help.

Comment: How are your creating the Error?  Tried this in a playground and I get an error for `NSError(operation: operation)`

Comment: NSError() doesn't matter.. it doesn't work even without those lines.